# Can't get email form to send email

Tags: html

Help please!!! I can't figure out how to get this form to send/ receive emails!

Am I missing anything?

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 forma">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 name" name='name' placeholder='Name *'/>
                    <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 Email" name='Email' placeholder='Email *'/>
                    <input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Subject" name='Subject' placeholder='Subject'/>
                    <textarea type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Message" name='Message' placeholder='Message *'></textarea>
                    <div class="cBtn col-xs-12">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="clear"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>clear form</a></li>
                            <li class="send"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share"></i>Send Message</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 cont">
                <ul>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Coconut Grove, FL</li>
                    <li><a href="MAILTO:email@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>email</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: _'Am I missing anything?'_ - yes: the entire server-side code required to process the form data and send an email.

Comment: You need a form processor, such as PHP to actually send the form. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Check out http://formr.github.io/blog/formr-for-designers/

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting this to actually send an email?  It just pops up your default mail client.  If you don't have a default mail client configured, it will not do anything.

also, your nesting is wrong, you are reversing the nesting of your li and a tags

```
  <li><a href="MAILTO:email@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>email</li></a>
```

Comment: How do I configure a default mail client so this form works properly?

Comment: This depends on your operating system.   Here, let me google that for you:  https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20configure%20mail%20client